# Custom column for different days

Tags: powerbi, customcolumn

I'm using DirectQuery and i want to calculate the start date - end date without the weekend (Friday and Saturday) through a custom column. Can you help me?

I want you to solve the problem according to the specifications I told you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the DAX [`NETWORKDAYS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/networkdays-dax) function.

It would look similar to:

```
My New Column = NETWORKDAYS([start date], [end date], 7)
```

And if it doesn't work for DirectQuery, then you will need to use a Measure instead. That could like this:

```
My New Measure = 
  var r = SUMX(
    'Your Table Name',
    NETWORKDAYS( [start date], [end date], 7 )
  ) 
  return IF( r < 0, 0, r)
```

Comment: It's not working with DirectQuery

Comment: See updated answer above - you will need to use a Measure instead of a Calculated Column.

Comment: When I use Measure, the columns do not accept the start and end dates and are underlined in red. There is an error

Comment: Can you send a screen grab of the code with the underlines please. Update your question above with it.

Comment: I used the last method and it worked fine, but a new problem arose, which is when the start date is the same as the end date, the difference between the two dates appears in the chart as " -2" . It should show zero, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure how that is possible, unless end is before start. Anyways, see updated answer.

Comment: I'm working on a ticketing project, and the goal is to calculate the number of days a ticket is open. However, I'm currently facing an issue. When a ticket opens before the weekend, specifically on Thursday, it should be counted as one day until Sunday and another day until Monday. However, it's currently being treated as a one day. I hope I've conveyed the issue correctly

Comment: The weekend in my country is Friday and Saturday

Comment: The `7` in `NETWORKDAYS` signifies Fri-Sat weekend. Have a look at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UV9h.png, is this wrong?

Comment: I will tell you what I did; I'm working on a direct query. I created a column that holds the today date and always updates to calculate the days between the open ticket date and the current date. However, when I created the table, I noticed that the today date stops at January 15th. I'm not sure if my column creation method is incorrect, causing it not to calculate correctly. Any insights?

Comment: Where and how did you create the column? At the data source or in Power BI? It might be stuck at that date since that was when it last refreshed? Guessing. Anyway, you could omit that column and instead update the `[end date]` to `COALESCE( [end date], TODAY() )`